# Microstrategy REST API

Tags: microstrategy

I know following are the ways to get table from MSTR REST API:
http://server:8080/MicroStrategyLibrary/api/searches/results?pattern=4&type=15

And below is the URL to fetch columns:
http://server:8080/MicroStrategyLibrary/api/searches/results?pattern=4&type=26&getAncestors=true

How will I get to know which column belongs to which table?? OR in generic terms REST API to give relation/dependency between objects.

Comment: I know there is a way through metadata repository, but the question is specific to REST API.

Comment: Make a connection to metadata repository and use SQL in your code to fetch all details.

Comment: Thanks GauravS, I know metadata repository stuff.

Comment: Post this question on MicroStrategy community https://community.microstrategy.com/. Chances of getting an answer are higher there.

Comment: So I had communication with Microstrategy support following is what they replied: 
Currently the MSTR REST API is not support to get the data on the warehouse level. In the case of report, what we can get is the data on the report level which has been processed based on the report structure.

Comment: okay, thanks for update.